# dynamic drop down menu items

Tags: views, navigation

I'm new in drupal and I would like to add a link Projects to the main navigation menu:

- Projects

  ```
    proj 1
    proj 2
    ...
    proj n
  ```

This link projects  with a drop down menu with N links.
Until now I can have this drop down menu but statically.

Q1. I would like to generate this drop down list dynamically. For example if I have 10 projects, the drop down menu will have 10 links. Is there a way to plug into the menu a drop down list result of a view? or a select list but in the menu?

Q2. For each project in the drop down menu, I would like to point to a page sending the node id of this selected node (the page have some block views). 
So I can use this node id in the contextual filters for the views I have in the pages.
Is there a way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: You could consider creating a taxonomy vocab called "Projects", with terms such as `proj_1, proj_2` etc - and then use the https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu to create them as menus. However this module gives you a taxonomy vocab as a separate menu block, so it won't quite integrate fully with the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

Q1. The module [Menu Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_views) allows you to "insert" views results in place of one menu item.

Q2. You'll need [Views Contextual Filter Query](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filter_query) and apply it to the views blocks you have on your pages.

Then you need to construct the links that have the project node id in query so it can be picked up by views on pages. The easiest way to do that is probably with Views. Create a new view listing pages, with Link to content as a field but override it to append the project id query, limit results to 1, details depend on your particular case, you haven't included enough info about the connections between projects and pages and possible other configuration.